# Unable to center HTML text section with Bootstrap for different screens sizes

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, centering

I have a section of text that I would like centered on every screen. However, whenever the screen size increases, It stays at the top, the bottom of the screens stays empty and it looks bad.

I am pasting the code and screenshots of how it is staying on top and not centering.

I have also marked that part in the code that adjusts the padding of the page from top. Don't know how to make it for center for all screens sizes. Thanks

```css
body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    font-family: Lora,"Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #000;
}

html {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
    margin: 0 0 35px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: Montserrat,"Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
    font-weight: 700;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
}

p {
    margin: 0 0 23px;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 1.5;
}

@media(min-width:768px) {
    p {
        text-align: justify;
        text-justify: inter-word;
        margin: 0 0 20px;
        font-size: 20px;
        line-height: 1.6;
    }
}

a {
    color: #3bc692;
    -webkit-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
    transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
    outline: 0!important;
}
@media(min-width:768px) {
    .adjust-this {
        padding-left: 55px; padding-right: 55px;
    }
}

.content-section {
    padding-top: 85px;
}

@media(min-width:767px) {
    .content-section {
        padding-top: 50px; /*This is where you can adjust padding for the section*/
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }
}

.content-section p {
    opacity: 0.9;
    font-family: 'Domine';
    font-size: 19px;
    font-weight: 500;
}

a:hover,
a:focus {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #1d9b6c;
}

.greeting {
    padding-top: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <title>About</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom CSS -->
    <link href="about.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom Fonts -->
    <link href="font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open Sans:400,700,400italic,700italic" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

</head>


<body>
 <!-- About Section -->
    <article id="about" class="content-section">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1 text-left adjust-this">
                    <h2 class="text-center greeting">Hi there!</h2>
                    <p>Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000
                    </p>
                    <p>
                    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. 

                    </p>
                    <p>
                    It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.                     
                    </p>

                    <p>
                      It uses a dictionary of over 200 Latin words, combined with a handful of model sentence structures, to generate Lorem Ipsum which looks reasonable. The generated Lorem Ipsum is therefore always free from repetition, injected humour, or non-characteristic words etc.
                      </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </article>
    </body>
```

[image: Small screen size]

[image: See how big screen bottom is empty]

Comment: Can you be more clear about what you're asking. Also this seems like an easy google question.

Comment: I want this text to be centered in the bigger screen and not stay at the top with the empty bottom

Comment: You can check several ways of centering here: https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/

Comment: @Alvaro The double centering on the page you linked me worked. If you wish to write it as an answer, I will accept it

Answer (score 2):

Vertical centering inside of a div isn't something that is out of the box with bootstrap.  It follows the rules you put in place for top padding.  Right now you are setting `padding-top: 85px;` which will not be flexible on different size screens.  Without specifying a height on your container you are unable to utilize `vertical-align: middle;` or flexbox centering.  But if you did declare a height those would be great solutions.

To continue using your current method you can just update the top padding you are applying based off the screen size:

```
@media(min-width: /*Specify screen size here*/ ) {
    .content-section {
        padding-top: 200px; /*add required top padding here*/
    }
}
```

Another more complicated solution would be to calculate the window height using jquery and add top padding that was a percentage of that window height.  Place the following code at the top of your `<body>` tag.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    var getPadding = function() { 
        $("#about").css("padding-top",function () {
            return (window.innerHeight*.15 + "px");
        });
    };
    getPadding();
    $( window ).resize(function() {
        getPadding();
    });
});
</script>
```

And here is a link to a working codepen:

http://codepen.io/egerrard/pen/BLxBBw

Comment: Not getting where to place this code since it is not taking effect. Can you plz help I will accept the answer

Comment: which solution are you trying to use?  Are you able to declare a height?  If so that would probably be the easiest to implement.  If not adding the top padding for various viewports will be the second easiest and that is just added into your css.

Comment: 2nd part you told..the jquery one

Comment: @Solly updated with a codepen link.  You'll need to make sure to include jquery in your project.  That code will calculate padding on the pages initial load and then also if the page is resized.  You'll probably need to play around with the amount of padding.  Right now it is adding 15% of page height.

Comment: @Solly if this worked for you can you mark it as the answer to close it?